# Request sql "update" in perl

Tags: sql, perl

I have a perl script that contains a sql update query type, but I can not lead to a result ,I broke the head for 3 days, I have not found the solution, someone help me

```
my $sth = $db->prepare('select idS from ocs.Storage where name like ? ');
$sth->bind_param(1,"$v4");
$sth->execute();
if ($sth->rows < 0)
{
print " sorry";
}
else
{
#print "found \n",$sth->rows;
 while (my $results = $sth-> fetchrow_hashref)
  {
    $idSt = $results->{idS};
  print "idst est $idSt et vm name est $test3[$d]";
  $idSt=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//;
  $idSt=~ s/\'//g;
  $idSt=~ s/\'//g;
  $idSt=~ s/\"//g;
  $idSt=~ s/^\s+//;
  $idSt=~ s/\s+$//;
  my $null=0;
  $idSt=$idSt +$null;
  my $statement1 = "UPDATE VM SET stoaregeA_id = ? where VM_OS = ?";
  $db5->do($statement1,undef,$idSt,$test3[$d]);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `$db5` is pointing to the correct database?

Make sure you have `strict`, and `warnings` switch on.

Additionally, to diagnose further and see what queries are actually running on `mysql`, run the following SQL commands:

```
-- Log all queries
set global general_log = 'ON';
set global log_output = 'TABLE';

-- Run after code execution
select * from mysql.general_log;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add more checks for your code and see if that give you anything more. Also please let us see what `$test3[$d]` and `$db5` is.
Include your table description as well. Might be something there that could give us a clue.

```
    my $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT idS FROM ocs.Storage WHERE name LIKE ?')
        or die("Error preparing: " . $db->errstr);
    $sth->bind_param(1, "$v4");
    $sth->execute
        or die("Error executing: " . $sth->errstr);
    if ($sth->rows < 0) {
        print " sorry";
    } else {
        while (my $results = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
            $idSt = $results->{idS};
            print "idst est $idSt et vm name est $test3[$d]";
            $idSt=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//;
            $idSt=~ s/\'//g;
            $idSt=~ s/\'//g;
            $idSt=~ s/\"//g;
            $idSt=~ s/^\s+//;
            $idSt=~ s/\s+$//;
            my $null = 0;
            $idSt = $idSt + $null;
            my $stmt = 'UPDATE VM SET stoaregeA_id = ? WHERE VM_OS = ?';
            $db5->do($stmt, undef, $idSt, $test3[$d])
                or die("Error doing: " . $db5->errstr);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If parameterized update is not working, try construct the final statement directly and print it out to debug.

Comment: i try this , the output is 0 modification , that's mean , the request it's true , but i have a small error :

Comment: my $a=$test3[$d];
my $requete = 'UPDATE VM SET stoaregeA_id = "$idSt" WHERE VM_OS like "$a%"';

my $prep = $db5->prepare($requete)
    or die 'Impossible de préparer la requête : '.$db5->errstr;

$prep->execute
    or die 'Impossible d\'exécuter la requête : '.$prep->errstr;

print 'Ligne(s) modifiée(s) : '.$prep->rows;

Comment: If you run this statement in your database directly, and it doesn't update as you expected,  you have a data or logic error, instead of coding issue.  You may want to post more details about your data and the final statement if you want us to help you debug.

Comment: I arrive at this point it is to update IDST with a 0 value  ***** my $requete = 'UPDATE VM SET stoaregeA_id = "$idSt" WHERE VM_OS like ? ';
my $prep = $db5->prepare($requete)
    or die 'Impossible de préparer la requête : '.$db5->errstr;
$prep->bind_param(1,$a."%");
$prep->execute
    or die 'Impossible d\'exécuter la requête : '.$prep->errstr;

print 'Ligne(s) modifiée(s) : '.$prep->rows;
*****